# Movie with world globe size red sphere

Tags: story-identification, movie, b-movies

I know there’s not much detail but a friend of mine is looking for a very specific movie. There is a late 80s or early 90s B or below Sci Fi movie out there that inspired a big red Chinese buoy gift from my friend’s late husband to her. In the movie, a dark haired woman goes up to some table or control panel and does something with a big round red thing. Can anyone help identify this movie? She used to tell people She wanted a big red thing (sphere).

Comment: Not a huge amount of detail here - is there anything else you remember about the movie.